# Fetching the token Failed, message : FIS_AUTH_ERROR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, expo

I'm using Expo to build 2 android app, and using 1 Firebase Project.
For Notification I'm using expo-notifications.
I had uploaded Firebase Server Key to Expo `expo push:android:upload --api-key XXX-XXX-XXX`.
I had configured android app credential in firebase Project Settings with SHA-1 from Google Play Console, then downloaded the latest `google-services.json`, then placed in `app.json` and set path `android.googleServicesFile : "./google-services.json"`.
I had configured package name API Google Cloud Platform same as `app.json` `android.package`, same as Android App Firebase Project Setting Package Name.
I had configured `SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint` API Google Cloud Platform and Android App Firebase Project Settings same as `SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint` from Google Play Console.
I had enabled `Firebase Installation API`, `Firebase Cloud Messaging`, `FCM Registration API`, `Cloud Messaging` in Google Cloud Platform.
I set single user login within my app, so When user did new login, the past of `usertoken` will be reset to a new token, and another login will be logout.
The problem is, one of my app works perfectly, and another one came out with error, it said, `Fetching the token Failed, message : FIS_AUTH_ERROR`.
And Notification is not delivered to broken app.
Help me please...

Comment: Good job on the question, really shows you've taken the time to research the issue on your own!  Are you sure you've rebuilt (`expo build:android`) your application after downloading `google-services.json`? Are you sure you've configured Firebase Server Key for both Expo apps and Firebase for both Android packages?

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem. Have gone through our set up steps again and can't see where we did anything wrong!

Comment: same problem here. Followed the documentation 1 to 1 and still I face the same error. When in developing mode everything is perfect and I receive a push token, when I run the standallone app the error with ```FIS_AUTH_ERROR``` occurs.

Comment: Same here after downloading the google-service.json file.Any news in this question?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Firebase Installations SDK (FIS) error was caused by either:

- Mismatch of the API key between google-services.json and google cloud console.
- Mismatch of the App Fingerprint that was whitelisted in the google cloud console. You can check the credentials of your app using `eas credentials`. You can check the current app fingerprint and add that to the 'whitelist' in google cloud console.